# Magento Validation for multiple fields

Tags: form-validation

I was looking for validation for multiple fields. There are a lot of tutorials/articles with single field validation. But how to create fully-working validation for combined fields - 2 (or more fields) with one message. For example, I'd like to validate:
XX YYY
where XX and YYY are different (input type text) fields.
I have created custom Validation.add() but there is still problem with adding/removing classes from both fields.
My code looks like this:

```
Validation.add('validate-postcode', Translator.translate('Please enter a valid post code.'), function (v, elm) {
    var elem1 = jQuery(elm),
        relatedElem = jQuery('#' + elem1.attr('data-related-field')),
        passed = false;
    if (typeof relatedElem !== 'undefined') {
        relatedElem.removeClass('validation-failed');
        relatedElem.removeClass('validation-passed');
        elem1.removeClass('validation-failed');
        elem1.removeClass('validation-passed');
        passed = !Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(elem1.val()) &&
                !Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(relatedElem.val()) &&
                /^\d{3}$/.test(elem1.val()) &&
                /^\d{2}$/.test(relatedElem.val());
        if (!passed) {
            relatedElem.addClass('validation-failed');
            elem1.addClass('validation-failed');
        }
    }
    return passed;
});
```

In this source data-related-field is the attribute for one field to be related with another - value of this attribute is id of related field.

Answer (score 1):

After few hours of experimenting I made some changes for previous code which works for my problem:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    Validation.add('validate-postcode', Translator.translate('Please enter a valid post code.'), function (v, elm) {
        var elem1 = jQuery(elm),
                relatedElem = jQuery('#' + elem1.attr('data-related-field')),
                passed;
        elem1.removeClass('validation-failed');
        elem1.removeClass('validation-passed');
        if (typeof relatedElem !== 'undefined') {
            relatedElem.removeClass('validation-failed');
            relatedElem.removeClass('validation-passed');
            passed = !Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(elem1.val()) &&
                    !Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(relatedElem.val()) &&
                    /^\d{3}$/.test(elem1.val()) &&
                    /^\d{2}$/.test(relatedElem.val());
            if (!passed) {
                relatedElem.addClass('validation-failed');
                elem1.addClass('validation-failed');
            }
        }
        return passed;
    });
});
```

Hope that help or inspire someone for better solution.
"Document ready" was required due Translator.translate() existence.
Translation of string "Please enter a valid post code." was added in jstranslator.xml file.

Comment: Thanks, can you please post your complete answer ?  where did you declare these rules in the form fields ? what does validation object is referencing to ?